# CefSharp not displaying PDF files in the builtin viewer

Tags: cefsharp, pdf-viewer

I'm writing a custom webbrowser based on CefSharp 90.6.7. I have a problem with opening PDF files. I'd like these files to be opened in the Chromium built in PDF viewer. Instead of this I just get a white screen with an error "The PDF cannot be loaded" message. There I have the possibility do download the PDF file and after downloading this gets displayed in the default PDF viewer.

Unfortunately I don't know how the web application is serving the PDF files (it's a SAP UI5 ABAP something), but when I try this in latest nightly Chromium, MS Edge or other Chromium based browsers, these correctly display the PDF file in the build in viewer.

Can you point me what do I miss? Is it somehow necessary to handle these PDF files? I tried to google for an example, but haven't found anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by checking the log file see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file

Comment: There's no default that I'm aware of that shows a an error message and provides the option to download,  this sounds like your website is showing the page. Open Devtools to find out more see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging also try loading a PDF from a different website.